# How can I activate Mac speech without pressing a key?

Tags: mac, voice-dictation

I just bought a microphone to test built in mac speech. On the speech preference, I can choose which keyboard key to make mac to listen to my voice.

Is it possible to make my mac to listen continuously without pressing a key?

I know that I can make mac listen to me without a voice command (ex: mac, [command]), but i don't like it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quoted directly from the Speech Recognition Settings preferences:

---

Listen only while key is pressed:

> With Speakable Items turned on, you can also select this method by
>   speaking the command “**Turn on push-to-talk.**”

Listen continuously with keyword:

> Use the “**Keyword is**” pop-up menu to change when you need to speak the
>   keyword. Use the Keyword field to specify what the keyword is.

---

[image: Speech Recognition Settings preferences]